# Which field did find the search query?

Tags: elasticsearch

ı want to find a field, Which field did find the search query?
this can be any query I am not writing a specific query

for example

ı searching `dilo abinin` phrase or any word, and found bellow document

```
{
  "name":"dilo abinin",
  "surname: "sürücü"
}
```

ı want to  get `name` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html), to see which field matched your query

**Index API**

```
{
  "name":"dilo abinin",
  "surname": "sürücü"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "dilo abinin"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65325154",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "name": "dilo abinin",
          "surname": "sürücü"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name": [                // note this
            "<em>dilo</em> <em>abinin</em>"
          ],
          "name.keyword": [
            "<em>dilo abinin</em>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @dılo sürücü did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: @dılo sürücü thank u for accepting the answer, can you please upvote the answer as well :)

Comment: Thanks @dılosürücü 

Comment: your  welcome , god will be blessing you :)

Comment: @dılosürücü thank you for your kind words 